# switch to root takes long time

Tags: root, performance, authentication, su

I have a system (RHEL) and switching to `root` takes about 1 minute. (`su - root`)
However, switching to any another user takes less than 1 second.
Is there a way to debug, why does switching to root take a lot of time? 
I believe, that there is some script which is performed just after switching and consumes this time, but I can't find path to this script.

**edit:** I try to perform bash --login --verbose and it seems, that this line takes all time:
/opt/vmware/bin/ovfenv --quiet --key vm.vmname

Does anybody know, what does this line do and how can I avaoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue (thanks this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413975/10-second-delay-between-login-and-shell-prompt)

The issue is in /etc/profile.d/zzzz-vamilocale.sh file, which is trying to read something from vm properties and stuck in that. removing this files solves the issue.